# TypeScript 1.4 compiler throwing error when compiling in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript1.4

I'm doing some simple tutorials with TypeScript 1.4 in Visual Studio 2013 and everything works fine when I am compiling in **debug**. As soon as I try to compile in **release** I get:

```
The command "tsctrue "C:\Users\dluther\Downloads\typescript\materials\2-typescript-m2-exercise-files\Code\Before\TypeScriptTypes\TypeScriptTypes\app.ts"
"C:\Users\dluther\Downloads\typescript\materials\2-typescript-m2-exercise-files\Code\Before\TypeScriptTypes\TypeScriptTypes\Scripts\02-05-primitives.ts""
exited with code 9009.
```

In my .csproj file I have this:

```
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Message Text="Compiling TypeScript files" />
        <Message Text="Executing tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'"%(fullpath)"', ' ')" />
        <Exec Command="tsc$(TypeScriptSourceMap) @(TypeScriptCompile ->'"%(fullpath)"', ' ')" />
    </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have this in my project file (I had to add it manually):

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <TypeScriptSourceMap> --sourcemap</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    </PropertyGroup>
```